# How to prevent component from re-rendering? (with MWE)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, react-hooks, components

How can I prevent a component from re-rendering when its props are **not** changed?

[Code sandbox link/minimal working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-shtern-3v7vx). Move your cursor over `Canvas` and see that the console is logged with many `"Canvas re-rendered"` messages.

At the top-level, I pass in a `const` function as a handler to the `Canvas`. The `onMouseMoveHandler` updates `App`'s state so that it can update the `Details` component:

```
<div className="App">
  <Canvas onMouseMoveHandler={onMouseMoveHandler} />
  <Details passedProp={getValue} />
</div>
```

I need it so that `Canvas` is not re-rendered because the HTML `canvas` element inside has user-drawn lines. How can I do this?

I would have thought that using `React.memo` would make it like a pure component so that it is not re-rendered.

I am a very beginner to React and if I am not thinking of the right code structure, let me know how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.js every time you call `setValue`, your `App` component rerenders and creates a new `onMouseMoveHandler` function.
Your `Canvas` component uses `React.memo` but since on each rerender `onMouseMoveHandler` gets a new reference, it also rerenders.
In order to prevent that you have to wrap your `onMouseMoveHandler` with `useCallback`. [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. .

Here's the example:

```
const onMouseMoveHandler = useCallback(() => {
   setValue(Math.random());
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap `onMouseMoveHandler` in a `useCallback` that should solve it. The problem is that when the state changes, your App-component re-renders and the `onMouseMoveHandler` function gets a new reference. And seeing as it has a new reference, this will cause the `Canvas` to re-render as well because it sees this as  a prop change. Using the `useCallback` hook you guarantee that the function reference stays intact between renders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **callBack** **hook**, because every time you change the state of the component **App**, you redefine the function **onMouseMoveHandler** so the value change and the props onMouseMoveHandler change so the component **Canvas** need to re-render.

You can check the modifications here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-water-72uq4?file=/src/App.js:362-380